# C чего начать изучать C++?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!

Я хотел бы освоить С++. Мне 15 лет, и я думаю с чего бы начать? Чтоб освоить всё в лучшем виде, где можно выучить всё в облегчённом виде, то есть я хочу найти начало длинной ниточки.

Вопрос: с чего начинать?

Comment: С чего начать - сам ищу, а вот сможешь освоить или нет.. тут только ты знаешь :)

Comment: Обратите внимание на вопрос: [С чего начать изучение языка программирования? Например C++](http://hashcode.ru/questions/12767/%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-c).

Answer (score 4):

Я бы на Вашем месте, начал не просто с зубрением книги, а прочитал бы основы - что такое переменная, функция и тому подобное. После искал бы интерактивные уроки, брал бы из них суть и практиковался на своих мыслях. Теория хорошо, но без практики - ничто, имхо.

Answer (score -2):

Начните со Страуструпа, замечательная книга, одна из лучших по С++.

Comment: Никогда, подчеркиваю никогда, не начинайте изучение C++ со Страуструпа - единственное, что вы из этого подчеркнете, - это неимоверная сложность языка, что скорей всего вас просто оттолкнет. На худой конец [вот](http://valera.asf.ru/cpp/book/c01.html).

Comment: Вот это неизвестно, оттолкнет или наоборот, как меня, привлечет. Да, согласен, язык избыточен, и кому-то это кажется сложностью.

Comment: Страуструп - это бесспорно вещь, стоящая и необходимая любому программисту C++, но начинать с неё изучение первого языка очень сложно, да и сам вопрос упирется на источники в "облегченном виде".

Comment: @ЕгорСоколов - Страуструп Страуструпу рознь. Программирование: принципы и практика использования С++ очень достойная и доступная новичкам книга.

Answer (score -2):

Я бы порекомендовал Сиддхартха Рао, "Освой самостоятельно C++ за 21 день, 7-е издание". 
Несмотря на кричащее название и национальность автора, мне, когда начинал разбираться, очень даже зашло.

Answer (score -2):

Очень рекомендую - Программирование: принципы и практика использования С++. В книге рассказывается в первую очередь о программировании в целом, и лишь в качестве инструмента программирования рассматривается С++. Недавно на русском вышло второе издание, но перевод оставляет желать лучшего - советую читать в оригинале.

Answer (score -3):

На мой взгляд, особо важно не только изучение синтаксиса, но и решение каких-то простейших задач. Поищите - в интернете есть много сайтов с задачами по программированию для начинающих как cppstudio.ru или скачайте книгу с задачами.